# use models in separate project as a foreign key in Django?

Tags: django-models

Possible stupid question: let's say I have two apps contained within one project. Can I use models from one app as foreign keys in the other app's models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to import the model from the other. For example

```
from thisproject.app2 import other_model
```

Then you should be able to use the other_model class